# ASP.Net WebForm and IIS rewrite rule for adding country code in all url

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module

sorry posting this kind of code without any effort because i have no basic idea handling this situation with iis rewrite rule. i have seen people handle this with iis rewrite rule but i am not aware what to write in web.config file for iis rewrite rule.

I have one small question regarding url rewrite. suppose i want to add country code in my all url say www.mysite.com/gb/home.aspx or www.mysite.com/de/home.aspx but there will be no folder  called gb or de rather when the above kind of url will be issued then i need to internally send the request to my root home.aspx file and country code will be passed as query string. how can i achieve this with IIS rewrite rule. i guess we need to handle it with iis rewrite rule but i do not know how iis rewrite rule would look like for this scenario. if anyone know then can share the code for iis rewrite rule which i need to write in web.config file.

please help me with sample iis rewrite rule which i need to write in web.config file.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the rewrite module, then following [these instructions](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) should help you.

I am no expert with regular expressions, but I imagine you will end up with a rewrite rule in the web config similar to something like this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite language code">
  <match url="^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+).aspx" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:2}.aspx?lang={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If you want to match only on a two character language code, then you could likely adjust the first match group to do so.

Comment: i have no idea the code here you shared. would mind to explain it. what does it means `url="^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+).aspx"` and `url="/{R:2}.aspx?lang={R:1}"` please explain it. thanks

Comment: the above rule would be inbound or outbound rule ?

Comment: It would be an inbound rule. The code is all regular expressions which match specific patterns. The linked page would explain better than I ever could, and regular expressions can get extremely complicated.