# ASP.Net WebForm: looking for guideline to understand IIS rewrite rule

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module

i post a question here and answer url is https://stackoverflow.com/a/42694565/6188148

the person gave a IIS rewrite rile snippet whose meaning is not clear to me.

```
<rule name="Rewrite language code">
  <match url="^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-z]+).aspx" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:2}.aspx?lang={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

just do not understand what is the meaning of this line `/{R:2}.aspx?lang={R:1}` what is {R:2} and {R:1}

How IIS would understand that `{R:2}.aspx` need to be replaced with `home.aspx` should be and {R:1} need to be replaced with country code. what logic is there to which causes replace.

what logic is there for which country name should be store in `{R:2}` template and country code will be stored in `{R:1}`

it my request that if some one familiar with this kind of rule then please put some light here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search pattern for a `match` consist of two parts, recognized by the pattern inside the brackets `()`. It is comparable to a `regex` in javascript.

`([a-z]+)` and `([0-9a-z]+)`

The rewrite module can now use these two as a token in the `action` part to rewrite the url. Because the 2 digit language code is the first match it gets assigned to `{R:1}`, the second is the actual page, so that becomes the second token `{R:2}`.

You could compare this to the `C#` usage of the `string.format` function where tokens are replaced by the overloaded string values.

```
string token = "value";
Label1.Text = string.Format("Replace {0}.", token)
```

More info:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/06/12/url-rewrite-part-2inbound-rules/

http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

https://besthostingforasp.net/url-rewrite-module-iis/

Comment: well explained.